# D3 axis lable scale

Tags: javascript, d3.js

trying to learn D3 and on the label axis seem to be stacked upon one another.
I have tried to turn the scale calls into reusable functions however this may be exacerbating the issue.
The data:

```
data=[];
data.push({'label':'#1','cost':15000,'saving':18000});
data.push({'label':'#2','cost':40000,'saving':65000});
data.push({'label':'#3','cost':55000,'saving':80000});
data.push({'label':'#4','cost':15000,'saving':30000});
```

The scale:

```
function getY(d){
    return yScale = d3.scaleBand()
        .domain(d3.range(0, d.length))
        .range([0, (height-20)])
        .paddingInner(0.1)
        .paddingOuter(0.1)
}
```

Trying to build the axis:

```
labels=[]
$.each(data,function(){
    labels.push(this.label);
})
var hAxis = d3.axisRight()
    .scale( getY(data) )
    .tickValues( labels )
```

Everything seems to be working but the labels seem to be receiving something incorrect on the translate:

`<g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(0,NaN)"><line stroke="#000" x2="6">`

Where is the NaN being received from, I assume an incorrectly coded scale.

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/L9mmy5d6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tickValues` specifies which values should have ticks, not what those ticks should look like. You can only specify values in the domain of the scale here.

If you have a standardized change you want (say, adding # to each number (and incrementing by one so that the numbers start at 1)), then you could use:

```
var hAxis = d3.axisRight()
    .scale( getY(data) )
    .tickFormat(function(d,i) { return "#"+(d+1) } )
```

([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oxkc8kur/))

Alternatively, if you want to pursue the same approach that you have, you could use something like:

```
var hAxis = d3.axisRight()
    .scale( getY(data) )
    .tickFormat(function(d,i) { return labels[i] })
```

([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1yrgpvz1/))

Keep in mind that your number of ticks should correspond to the the number of labels if using the index. You could also use `d` to set the label in this case, as the tick marks correspond to the index.

Comment: I see - I was getting `tickValues` and `tickFormat` confused. Thank you. I used the later to receive the label name from the inputted data.